# JSbarcode not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, pug, barcode, jsbarcode

I am trying to create a route in a nodejs app that generates a barcode from an objectId on a jade template   However, as I included my route and refresh, the images is not rendering.

I've read the documentation and tried different methods but it is not rendering still.

Here is my barcode.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('barcode', { title: 'Barcode' });

JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi!");


});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my jade template:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title

 svg#barcode
```

When i refresh the page, nothing shows (blank page)

What i am trying to do is get the image to render first and then eventually add more logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After res.render you can't have any line of code, since the page would render.

Change your barcode.js file as mentioned below

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('barcode', { title: 'barcode' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Change your barcode.jade file as mentioned below

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    svg#barcode
    script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.8.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js")
    script.
      JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi!");
```

This should give you a barcode on the page. Then you could look into sending ObjectId to the jade file for the new barcode to be generated.